# ContentURL XCDYouTubePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

XCDYouTubePlayer which to initialize the same way as you do with MPMoviePlayerController. How can i play multiple videos with this (making a playlist). In MpMoviePlayerController. i can set a ContentUrl Property while playing the movie and then when the other movie end start the new movie. How can i do this in the XCDYoutubePlayer which is quite the same?

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController =
[[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[playlists valueForKey:@"link"] objectAtIndex:rowNow]]];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: videoPlayerViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of my answer to [issue #16](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/16) of XCDYouTubeKit.

First, you need to unregister for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` in order for the player not to dismiss automatically at the end of the video.

```
static void *MoviePlayerContentURLContext = &MoviePlayerContentURLContext;

- (IBAction) play:(id)sender
{
    self.videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:firstVideoIdentifier];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.videoPlayerViewController name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [self.videoPlayerViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"moviePlayer.contentURL" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)0 context:MoviePlayerContentURLContext];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.videoPlayerViewController];
}
```

Then you need to handle the notification yourself. Manage *hasNextVideo* and *nextVideoIdentifier* how it makes sense for you.

```
- (void) moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMovieFinishReason finishReason = [notification.userInfo[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    if (finishReason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded && [self hasNextVideo])
        self.videoPlayerViewController.videoIdentifier = [self nextVideoIdentifier];
    else
        [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

You also need to register yourself as an observer of the movie player `contentURL` to automatically start playing the next video.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == MoviePlayerContentURLContext)
        [self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
    else
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```